# При запуске mysql в docker ошибка

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

Есть проект в котором использую связку `nginx` + `php` + `mysql` + `phpmyadmin` на которой в совою очередь поднимаю `laravel`. при запуске стартую все сервисы кроме `mysql`, файл `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./public_html:/var/www
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
#      - ./php.ini:/
    container_name: wp-nginx
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./public_html:/var/www
    container_name: wp-php
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    command: wp-mysql --innodb-flush-method=O_DSYNC --innodb-use-native-aio=0 --log_bin=ON
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: star
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: wp-mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      #MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    container_name: wp-phpmyadmin
```

`docker logs laravel-docker_mysql_1` показывает ошибку:

```
$ docker logs laravel-docker_mysql_1
2019-11-19 20:37:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server  started.
2019-11-19 20:37:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2019-11-19 20:37:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server  started.
2019-11-19 20:37:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2019-11-19 20:37:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 0 pages than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2019-11-19 20:37:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-11-19 20:37:53 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-11-19 20:37:53 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-11-19 20:37:53 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-11-19 20:37:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql/ for more information.

The problem could be conflicting information in an external
my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf

You can also try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --general-log &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql/ that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://mariadb.org/jira
```

Все это дело запускается на win10, на linux`е все работает отлично. Но возможности пока поставить линукс на домашнюю машину нет.

В чем может быть проблема с докером?

Comment: Проблема с виндой, попробуйте заменить image mariadb на mysql.

Comment: @Bat1stuff пробовал, тоже самое. Может быть такое что эта ошибка связана с оперативной памятью? на этой машине у меня всего 8 гб, когда запускается докер свободно где-то 3-3.5 гб.

Comment: Скорее всего вот тут https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/95#issuecomment-391587301  ответ на ваш вопрос. Правда `Issue is still active for mariadb:10.4.8-bionic with Windows 10.`

Comment: Проблему решил путём добавления в `docker-compose.yml` в раздел `mysql` в `volume` строки `- ./db/docker.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf`

содержание `docker.cnf` 
`[mysqld]
innodb_flush_method=littlesync
innodb_use_native_aio=OFF
log_bin=ON`